# Understanding coding syntax

Tags: powershell, syntax, parameters

I would like to give me a link or a document where I Can understand coding syntax of a help manual of a specific programming language.

In the command below, for example, what is the meaning of [] or []<String[]> or []<>{| | |} ?

I hope that you understand my question

```
Get-ChildItem [[-Path] <String[]>] [[-Filter] <String>] [-Attributes {read-only | Hidden | System | Directory |
    Archive | Device | Normal | Temporary | SparseFile | ReparsePoint | Compressed | Offline | NotContentIndexed |
    Encrypted | IntegrityStream | NoScrubData}] [-Depth <UInt32>] [-Directory] [-Exclude <String[]>] [-File] [-Force]
    [-Hidden] [-Include <String[]>] [-Name] [-Read Only] [-Recurse] [-System] [-UseTransaction] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [about_Command_Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_syntax?view=powershell-7.2) on the official Powershell documentation.

> SYNTAX DIAGRAMS
>
> Each paragraph in a command syntax diagram represents
> a valid form of the command.
>
> To construct a command, follow the syntax diagram from left to right.
> Select from among the optional parameters and provide values for the
> placeholders.
>
> PowerShell uses the following notation for syntax diagrams.
>
> ```
> <command-name> -<Required Parameter Name> <Required Parameter Value>
> [-<Optional Parameter Name> <Optional Parameter Value>]
> [-<Optional Switch Parameters>]
> [-<Optional Parameter Name>] <Required Parameter Value>
> ```

Regarding `<>`

> The .NET type of a parameter value is enclosed in angle brackets < >
> to indicate that it is placeholder for a value and not a literal that
> you type in a command.

`{}`

> Braces {} indicate an "enumeration," which is a set of valid values
> for a parameter.

`[]`

> A right and left bracket [] appended to a .NET type indicates that the
> parameter can accept one or multiple values of that type. Enter the
> values in a comma-separated list.

I won't copy paste everything but head up there to get more insights on the syntax.

Comment: Revisiting this helpful answer, let me suggest two improvements: It's worth mentioning that `[-<Optional Parameter Name>]` parameters are called _positional parameters_. May be worth adding the `[[-<Optional Parameter Name>] <Optional Parameter Value>]` variant (currently missing from the docs), i.e. an optional positional parameter (an example is `Start-Process`' `-ArgumentList` parameter).